# MS Access 2013: Why is my RIGHT JOIN query not returning a NULL when there is no match?

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2013

I have a custom table with an `ID` field (autonumber) and an `item` field. I have another table provided by my company with many fields, but it also has an `item`, `whse`, and `qty_on_hand` field.

I want to find only the items listed in the custom table, so I use a RIGHT JOIN. *However*, I also need to filter on some criteria. I need the 'whse = A' and 'qty_on_hand > 0', but when I do this it excludes items where there is no match instead of just returning a `NULL`. How can I make it so that all of the rows in the custom table are returned and if there is no match just return `NULL`?

I primarily use the Design View in Access, but this is the SQL as created by my working in Design View:

```
SELECT 
     customtable.ID
     ,customtable.item
     ,Sum(companytable.qty_on_hand) AS SumOfqty_on_hand
     ,companytable.whse
FROM companytable 
     RIGHT JOIN customtable ON companytable.item = customtable.item
GROUP BY 
     customtable.ID
     ,customtable.item
     ,companytable.whse
HAVING 
     (((Sum(companytable.qty_on_hand))>0) 
     AND ((companytable.whse)="A"))
ORDER BY 
     customtable.ID;
```

Comment: Do you see the Nulls you expect if you remove the `HAVING` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch this over to a `LEFT JOIN` so that you can apply some filtering to the `companytable` in your `ON` clause which would cause those records in your `companytable` to drop before being joined:

```
SELECT customtable.ID,
    customtable.item,
    Sum(companytable.qty_on_hand) AS SumOfqty_on_hand,
    companytable.whse
FROM customtable
LEFT JOIN companytable ON 
    companytable.item = customtable.item AND
    companyTable.qty_on_hand > 0 AND
    companyTable.whse = "A"
GROUP BY customtable.ID,
    customtable.item,
    companytable.whse   
ORDER BY customtable.ID;
```

I'm not sure how Access will represent that in it's "design" view, but it should work just fine.

Alternatively, you could use a subquery that filters the `companytable` before joining:

```
SELECT customtable.ID,
    customtable.item,
    Sum(comptable.qty_on_hand) AS SumOfqty_on_hand,
    comptable.whse
FROM (SELECT * FROM companytable WHERE qty_on_hand > 0 AND whse = "A") AS comptable
RIGHT JOIN customtable ON comptable.item = customtable.item
GROUP BY customtable.ID,
    customtable.item,
    comptable.whse
ORDER BY customtable.ID;
```

Comment: With the 1st option I'm getting an error message: `JOIN expression not supported.`"

Comment: 2nd option worked perfectly. I get all of the items in the custom table and show blanks for the `qty_on_hand` and the `whse`. Thank you.